# Отдельное рабочее пространство для каждой задачи

Tags: eclipse

При работе над проектом часто необходимо переключаться между задачами. Например, сейчас я работаю над задачей A и мне нужны открытые вкладки в Eclipse: TaskA1.java, TaskA2.java

Потом я переключаюсь на задачу B и мне нужны открытые вкладки TaskВ1.java, TaskВ2.java

После этого, я хочу переключиться на задачу A и так, чтобы я начал работать с того же места, где закончил в прошлый раз.

Получается, что-то вроде небольшого workspace для каждой задачи.

Есть ли какое-то решение в Eclipse для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Важное дополнение.

Совсем забыл про [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/), поскольку почти не пользуюсь. Вообще это довольно продвинутая штука для управления задачами, но в самом простом варианте можно и для решения вопроса легко приспособить.

Открываем вьюху "Mylyn | Task List". В ней создаём локальную задачу с именем проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Картинка побольше](http://xxo.su/resizer/i/8/c/532f69f8.png)

И не задаём больше ничего. Только отмечаем "Not Scheduled":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Картинка побольше](http://xxo.su/resizer/i/b/3/935080e.png)

Создаём вторую такую же задачу, открыв другой проект.

После чего активируем задачи по очереди и получаем контексты разных проектов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Картинка побольше](http://xxo.su/resizer/i/e/0/e833bbc1.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Картинка побольше](http://xxo.su/resizer/i/c/3/ff7ede10.png)

---

Для этого в Eclipse существует понятие `workspace`. Запустить Eclipse в конкретном воркспейсе можно так:

```
eclipse -data полный_путь_к_workspace
```

То есть структура на диске будет такая, по одному проекту на воркспейс (можно и по несколько, но это вроде бы по условиям не подходит):

```
/workspace1/project1
/workspace2/project2
/workspace3/project3
...
```

В самой IDE переключение делается через `File / Switch workspace > ...`

P.S. По мне так не самый удачный подход, предпочитаю концепцию "Working set". Несохранение открытых вкладок - мелочь по сравнению с сохранением рабочей среды со всеми глобальными настройками, включая настройи вьюх, перспектив и прочего. А они не будут автоматически попадать в другие воркспейсы, если сделаны в одном из них.

Comment: Да, но если задач с десяток за день - переключение между ними превращается в бесконечную загрузку воркспейсов.

Comment: @YuriiMikhailichenko,  вот и поэтому тоже `P.S.` написан. А пользоваться воркспейсами или нет - решать вам.

Comment: @YuriiMikhailichenko, а можно поковыряться в маркетплейсе, вдруг какой плагин найдётся для сохранения вкладок при переключении проектов?

Comment: Получилось реализовать с помощью плагина Mylyn